# Approximation Property: Characterization

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

*As reference the german wiki: [Approximationseigenschaft](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximationseigenschaft)*

**Problem**

Given a Banach space.

Suppose it has the approximation property:
$$C\in\mathcal{C}:\quad\|T_N-1\|_C\to0\quad(T_N\in\mathcal{F}(E))$$

Then every compact operator is of almost finite rank:
$$\overline{\mathcal{F}(X,E)}=\mathcal{C}(X,E)\subseteq\mathcal{B}(X,E)$$

How do I prove this actual equivalence?

**Attempt**

As the image of the unit ball is precompact one has:
$$C\in\mathcal{C}(X,E):\quad\|T_NC-C\|=\|T_N-1\|_{C(B)}\to0\quad(T_NC\in\mathcal{F}(X,E))$$
For the converse one might try to smuggle in a compact operator:
$$C\subseteq rB:\quad\|T_N-1\|_C\leq r\|T_N-C\|_B+\|C-1\|_C<r\delta_T+\delta_C\quad(C\in\mathcal{C}(E))$$
But how to construct one that approximates the identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nontrivial result by Grothendieck!

*(See Lindenstrauss & Tzafriri, Theorem 1.e.4, Volume I.)*