# Compact Approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

*This is meant as lemma for: [Approximation Property](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1122760/79762)*

Given a Banach space $E$.

Denote compact operators by $\mathcal{C}(E)$.

Consider a compact domain $C\subseteq E$.

Then there is a compact approximate identity:
$$C_N\in\mathcal{C}(E,E):\quad\|C_N-1\|_C:=\sup_{x\in C}\|C_Nx-x\|\stackrel{N\to\infty}\to0$$

How to construct such compact operators?

Comment: @tomasz: Banach space $E$, compact sets $\mathcal{C}$ and compact operators $\mathcal{C}(E)$; natural number $N$.

Comment: @tomasz: Yep: $\|\cdot\|_C:=\sup_{x\in C}\|x\|$

Comment: @tomasz: Do you have an idea how to construct such operators?

Comment: @tomasz: Yes good that you asked!

Comment: @tomasz: I was thinking about first clustering the compact set by small balls. Then taking the closed span of their centers to obtain a separable Banach space at least. But then it gets hard as how to build an appropriate operator by duals.

Comment: I edited the question to incorporate the missing explanation. Please check if I have done it correctly.

Comment: @tomasz: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not always true!

Banach spaces which admit a compact approximation are said to possess the CAP.

*(Enflo actually gave a counterexample for the CAP.)*